# Why is ExecuteResult not called?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jsonp

I'm trying to implement a JSONP response in my ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. I've followed this tutorial:
http://www.ingeniumweb.com/blog/post/using-jsonp-calls-in-asp.net-mvc/1216/

The problem is that the ExecuteResult method is never called:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace subscribe.ActionResults 
{
public class JsonpResult : JsonResult
{
    object Data = null;

    public JsonpResult()
    { 
    }

    public JsonpResult(object Data)
    {
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext ControllerContext)
    {
        if (ControllerContext != null)
        {
            HttpResponseBase Response = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response;
            HttpRequestBase Request = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

            string callbackfunction = Request["callback"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(callbackfunction))
            {
                throw new Exception("Callback function name must be provided in the request!");
            }
            Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
            if (Data != null)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                Response.Write(string.Format("{0}({1});", callbackfunction, serializer.Serialize(Data)));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
public JsonpResult Get(string emailaddress, string callback, string jsonp)
    {
        var slist = from u in db.subscriptions
                    select u;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailaddress))
            slist = slist.Where(s => (s.emailaddress == emailaddress));

        if (slist.Count() > 0)
        {
            JsonpResult result = new JsonpResult(slist.ToList());
            return result; //json list of matches
        }
        else
        {
            JsonpResult result = new JsonpResult(new List<Subscription>());
            return result; //empty json list
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you invoking your JsonpResult? Could you post a segment from your controller where it is used?

Comment: I updated the question with segment from my controller.

Comment: The code worked when I tried it, but I'm only returning a dummy list with one item. Are you calling your action like this? `~/ControllerName/Get?emailaddress=example@example.com&callback=functionName&jsonp=foo` (ignore the fact I didn't escape the '@' sign)

Comment: Weird I'm calling it the same way: http://localhost:20696/api/list/?emailaddress=person@example.com&jsonp=true&callback=functionName

Comment: I guess my next question is, how in your HTML and JavaScript are you invoking that action? Feel free to post that code also. When I tested my version, I ran it directly in the web browser address bar so I wouldn't have to write JavaScript to invoke the JSONP action.

Comment: I'm also just typing that into my address bar. The response I get displayed in Chrome is: {"Data":null,"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"JsonRequestBehavior":1,"MaxJsonLength":null,"RecursionLimit":null}

Comment: I noticed that your route uses "/api", which is the convention in WebAPI. Is this by any chance what you're using? I tried your example in an MVC Controller, not an ApiController.

Comment: Yes I'm making an API to use with AngularJS.